# Ldd shows a weird library "do_not_link_against_nvinfer_builder_resource" that doesn't match linker logs

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, bazel, elf

I'm trying to link a new library to my project `libnvinfer_builder_resource.so.8.5.1`, but I got this error when running it.

```
bazel-out/host/bin/gen_trt_ops_py_wrappers_cc: error while loading shared libraries: do_not_link_against_nvinfer_builder_resource: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and ldd shows that it's actually linking a strange library instead of the one I added
`do_not_link_against_nvinfer_builder_resource => not found .`

I debugged this a bit by enabling verbose logging for linker (tried both lld and gold), and they both show the correct library is found and linked.

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: Attempt to open bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_solib_local/_U@local_Uconfig_Ucuda_S_Scuda_Ccufft___Ucuda_Slib64/libnvinfer_builder_resource.so.8.5.1 failed
/usr/bin/ld.gold: Attempt to open bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_solib_local/_U@local_Uconfig_Ucuda_S_Scuda_Ccurand___Ucuda_Slib64/libnvinfer_builder_resource.so.8.5.1 failed
/usr/bin/ld.gold: Opened new descriptor 9 for "bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_solib_local/_U@tensor_Urt_S_S_Ctensor_Urt___Ulib/libnvinfer_builder_resource.so.8.5.1"
/usr/bin/ld.gold: Attempt to open bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_solib_local/_U@tensor_Urt_S_S_Ctensor_Urt___Ulib/libnvinfer_builder_resource.so.8.5.1 succeeded
/usr/bin/ld.gold: Unlocking file "bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_solib_local/_U@tensor_Urt_S_S_Ctensor_Urt___Ulib/libnvinfer_builder_resource.so.8.5.1"
/usr/bin/ld.gold: Released descriptor 9 for "bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_solib_local/_U@tensor_Urt_S_S_Ctensor_Urt___Ulib/libnvinfer_builder_resource.so.8.5.1"
/usr/bin/ld.gold: Closed descriptor 9 for "bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_solib_local/_U@tensor_Urt_S_S_Ctensor_Urt___Ulib/libnvinfer_builder_resource.so.8.5.1"
```

And by searching I can't find any log about `do_not_link_against_nvinfer_builder_resource` .

So I'm wondering why linker links the correct `libnvinfer_builder_resource.so.8.5.1`, but it becomes `do_not_link_against_nvinfer_builder_resource` in the ldd?

Comment: You should be adding that in your shared_libraries of the build file                                         'shared_libraries = ["abc.so", "xyz.so" ]'

Comment: @SG_Bazel Same, it also links the library when building the targets. Not sure if there is a way to only link the library at runtime

Comment: you shouldn't link against that library.  It is loaded dynamically when needed.  Of course, it can also fail to dynamically load, which is the subject of https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/issues/2218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the author of TensorRT used a hack to add a `do_not_link_against_nvinfer_builder_resource` to `libnvinfer_builder_resource.so.8.5.1`. We can confirm this with `readelf -d libnvinfer_builder_resource.so.8.5.1`